# Excel VBA Add-In code throws type mismatch error

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

We have developed an addin to translate things like account numbers / names and cost center number / names from our new system to our old system and vice versa.  It was working until today when I started getting a type mismatch error (run time error 13).

Our addin has multiple sheets.  1 sheet for branches, 1 sheet for accounts, etc.  The form used to do the translations accesses the appropriate sheet to retrieve the data to do the translation.  Following is a couple of variables and how they are declared:

```
Public UB as long
Public ThisAddIn as string

ThisAddIn = "TranslateAddIn.xla"

'Below is the part of the code that is causing the error.

UB = Workbooks(ThisAddIn).Worksheets("Branches").Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

I've checked the "Branches" sheet and don't see anything unusual with the data on this sheet.

I'm not sure what is going on.  This code has worked for years without any issues.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe row is an int? Maybe try defining UB as variant to see if that solves it?

Comment: @tomatosource `Integer` and `Long` both hold numeric values, just one has a larger amount of memory allocated and therefore can hold bigger numbers - You should always use `Long` when referring to row numbers as `Integer` is only a 16-bit data type, so any numbers over 32,767 will cause an overflow error

Comment: @MacroMan thanks for that, good to know. Wasn't sure how 'type-rigid' vba is.

Answer (score 0):

Try fully qualifying the range object in your find method. Something like:

```
Public UB as long
Public ThisAddIn as string

ThisAddIn = "TranslateAddIn.xla"

'Below is the part of the code that is causing the error.

With Workbooks(ThisAddIn).Worksheets("Branches")
    UB = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
End With
```

Comment: ..........thanks I'm going to give this a try and see if that resolves my issue.....

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately you can not refer to worksheet in the other workbook by its name, you should use index instead.

Comment: As long as the worksheet object is qualified with a workbook object, you can refer to it using its sheet name.